# does ng1x or ng2+ have a jquery dependency as part of its core framework?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular

Does ng1x or ng2+ use jquery as part of its core framework? I'm not that familiar with ng1x but based on my work with ng2+, I was under the impression that it had no jquery dependency. My manager has used ng1x in the past and he was under the impression that ng1x had a jquery dependency. So I wanted to run this by those on this forum who are more familiar with these frameworks and may know the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

From the angularjs docs:

> Does AngularJS use the jQuery library? Yes, AngularJS can use jQuery
>   if it's present in your app when the application is being
>   bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, AngularJS
>   falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we
>   call jQLite.
>
> AngularJS 1.3 only supports jQuery 2.1 or above. jQuery 1.7 and newer
>   might work correctly with AngularJS but we don't guarantee that.

For angular 2 I believe they removed it altogether but it can be injected easily if needed.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS does not depend on JQuery-- it has it's own version called jqLite.  If you include a JQuery script above your Angular `<script>` tag, AngularJS will use that instead.  https://gist.github.com/esfand/9638882

> Angular doesn’t depend on jQuery. In fact, the Angular source contains an embedded lightweight alternative: jqLite. Still, when Angular detects the presence of a jQuery version in your page, it uses that full jQuery implementation in lieu of jqLite.

I believe any dependence on JQuery-esque functionality was completely removed from Angular 2+, though

Comment: Is jqLite a subset of jQuery that was written and is maintained specifically by Angular team?

Comment: Are 3rd-party ng2 controls which have a jQuery dependency generally frowned upon by ng2 architects?  I.e. do ng2 architects generally have a no-use policy against third-party ng2 controls with a jQuery dependency?

Comment: For the first question, it appears that jqLite is maintained by the AngularJS team: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/jqLite.js.  I don't know about the second...  It depends on your overall approach.  Most of what you need to do can be done in Angular [2+], though some things are faster with jQuery if you have that knowledge.  However, be careful using jQuery because you may modify things without Angular [2+] knowing/recognizing any of the changes, which can cause issues.